# nodejs v8.getHeapStatistics method

Tags: node.js, memory, v8

In nodejs v8 module, there's a function called [getHeapStatistics](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html#v8_v8_getheapstatistics) which return an object that contains information about memory usage:

```
{ 
  total_heap_size: 221540352,
  total_heap_size_executable: 5242880,
  total_physical_size: 221540352,
  total_available_size: 1286110104,
  used_heap_size: 189179192,
  heap_size_limit: 1501560832,
  malloced_memory: 16384,
  peak_malloced_memory: 1325112,
  does_zap_garbage: 0 
}
```

What's the meaning of each field?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Some good explanation from [gc-heap-stats package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gc-heap-stats):

- total_heap_size: Number of bytes V8 has allocated for the heap. This can grow if usedHeap needs more.
- used_heap_size: Number of bytes in used by application data
- total_heap_size_executable: Number of bytes for compiled bytecode and JITed code
- heap_size_limit: The absolute limit the heap cannot exceed (default limit or --max_old_space_size)
- total_physical_size: Committed size

From [Node.JS docs](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html):

- does_zap_garbage is a 0/1 boolean, which signifies whether the --zap_code_space option is enabled or not. This makes V8 overwrite heap garbage with a bit pattern. The RSS footprint (resident memory set) gets bigger because it continuously touches all heap pages and that makes them less likely to get swapped out by the operating system.

Self descriptive:

- total_available_size: Available heap size
- malloced_memory: current amount of memory, obtained via malloc
- peak_malloced_memory: peak amount of memory, obtained via malloc

Comment: "Other fields are pretty self descriptive." I disagree, someone coming in here through google may be trying to find out about one of these specifically, in order to learn. if not to much trouble, I would like you to expand your answer to include the missing parts, even if it's to you "self descriptive" :) to the next person it may not be

Comment: Ok, I expanded my answer.

Comment: Wondering, how peak_malloced_memory is obtained and how long is it kept for statistic purposes...

Comment: what is total_available_size? is it `total_heap_size - used_heap_size`? is it `heap_size_limit - used_heap_size 
 - total_heap_size_executable`? this does not seem self descriptive

Answer (score 2):

There's [V8 API documentation directly generated from the sources](http://v8.paulfryzel.com/docs/master/classv8_1_1_heap_statistics.html), but the details of HeapStatistics are not explained.