# How to get the value of max_old_space_size from the code?

Tags: node.js, memory, garbage-collection

As I understand it is possible to set a maximum memory usage limit for an application like this:

```
node --max_old_space_size=500 app.js
```

Is it possible to get a value of the `max_old_space_size` from the code?

**UPDATE**

With the help of @Grégory NEUT we found out that `v8.getHeapStatistics()` contains a field `heap_size_limit` which looks like what I am looking for.

However I'm still not sure about it since I didn't find any official documentation (or some piece of code from Node.js) which will approve this theory.

I also don't understand why `heap_size_limit` becomes `557842432` bytes (`557.8` MB) when I set `max_old_space_size` to `500` MB

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the **Node.js v9.4.0 Documentation** you can find the function [v8.getHeapStatistics()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/v8.html#v8_v8_getheapstatistics) that gives you the heap size information.

**UPDATE 2019**: [Node.js v11.x Documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/v8.html#v8_v8_getheapstatistics)

---

**LEQADA Example from the comment:**

For `max_old_space_size=500`

`heap_size_limit : 557842432`

`total_available_size : 548898944`

---

For `max_old_space_size=900`

`heap_size_limit : 977272832`

`total_available_size : 968329344`

---

### [image]

---

**EDIT : process.memoryUsage() do not give informations about the max size of the heap**

---

In the **Node.js v9.4.0 Documentation** you can find the function [process.memoryUsage()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage) that gives you the heap size information.

**UPDATE 2019**: [Node.js v11.x Documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I checked it. Looks like it is not the same. The value of `heapTotal` is the same `7159808` for different `max_old_space_size` values

Comment: @LEQADA oh ok, gonna check if there is something else. Thanks for checking it out and sorry

Comment: @LEQADA What about [v8.getHeapStatistics()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/v8.html#v8_v8_getheapstatistics) ?

Comment: Thank you for the update! Looks like it is `heap_size_limit` or `total_available_size`. For `max_old_space_size=500` `heap_size_limit` returns `557842432`, `total_available_size` returns `548898944`. For  `max_old_space_size=900` `heap_size_limit` returns `977272832`, `total_available_size` returns `968329344`

Comment: Great job! :) Now maybe someone very strong can explain to us why there is such a difference between the limit and the actual value :D I guess something like memory pageSize or something

Comment: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47768386/980828. It says that "`heap_size_limit`: The absolute limit the heap cannot exceed (default limit or `--max_old_space_size`)". So looks like the answer is `heap_size_limit`. Now the question is why 500 MB is 557842432 bytes.

Comment: old_space is just the largest configurable section of the heap, it's not all of the heap. 
557842432 is 532MB..that's the total heap managed.
the old_space (where objects live before garbage collected) is 500MB.