# v8.getHeapStatistics() units

Tags: node.js, heap-memory

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41541843/1999993) asks what the various values returned by `v8.getHeapStatistics()` are, but I'm still not clear what the units are.

I would *expect* the units of those relating to memory/heap size to all be bytes.

However, I'm trying to debug an apparent memory leak in a NodeJS app, and am periodically writing out the `used_heap_size` as a percentage of the `total_available_size` to see how quickly the heap fills up, and I'm seeing some very odd output.

The heap apparently gets to just over 10,000% (yes, ten thousand percent) full before the app crashes with:

`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

So either I'm misunderstanding the relationship between `used_heap_size` and `total_available_size`, or else they don't have the same units.  (Or there's conceivably a bug, I suppose.)

[The docs](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html#v8getheapstatistics) say that they're both numbers, which is only helpful to a point.

Am I making an incorrect assumption?  Am I misunderstanding the values?

Comment: 10,000 is 100 squared. Is there any chance this is a bug on your side and you're multiplying by 100 twice?

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik :-)  Yes, I did wonder that myself actually!  I'm always paranoid about posting questions here where I've been daft, so I checked, and the percentage is calculated thus: `const mem = v8.getHeapStatistics(), percentage = Math.round( (100 * mem.used_heap_size) / mem.total_available_size );`.